# How Airflow can create a dataflow job from a python operator?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, apache-beam, dataflow

When I am running my Beam pipeline by the command line, using the direct runner or the dataflow runner, it works fine...

Example:

```
$ python my_pipeline.py --key /path/to/gcp/service/key.json --project gcp_project_name
```

But when I am trying to use airflow, I have two options, bash operator or python operator.

Using bash operator will success, but will limit my ability to use the airflow features.

But what I am trying to do is to run it as a python operator. So I am importing the module inside the airflow dg file, and then run it as a python operator.

It is also working fine if I am using the local runner, but when I changed it to the data flow runner, it fails after creating the job on GCP dataflow with this error

`ImportError: No module named airflow.bin.cli`

What I am missing to let **Airflow** create a **dataflow** job from a **python** operator?

Comment: Have you ever tried run other python tasks by python operator? Did you succeed? I used to play with Airflow and this error looks like Airflow setup problem.

Comment: Yes, I have multiple python operators, one of them only creating a dataflow job. And this error appears after the airflow creating the dataflow job already...

Answer (score 0):

OK,
That is not the perfect solution to it, but you can use

```
DataFlowPythonOperator()
```

which will run the exact same bash command we mentioned before.
It is a workaround and not equal to the `PythonOperator` but more like running a `BashOperator`...
Still can't use the strength of Airflow features in the current case (like xcom)...
[Docs](https://airflow.apache.org/integration.html#dataflowpythonoperator)

Comment: How can we pass input-file location and output location in DataFlowPythonOperator() ?